# Excel only follow hyperlink with CTRL + Left Click

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I don't like excels default of following hyperlinks when clicking on cell. I'd like to adjust it so that you have to press `CTRL` while clicking the cell to follow hyperlink.

I found this post on SU https://superuser.com/a/739899/465645 which has a great idea, but uses "formula" and in the comments there was this:

@ Engineer Toast

> I think VBA is the only way to do it. I would propose that you don't
> have to use the HYPERLINK function, though. You could also use
> Target.Hyperlinks(1).Address (with error trapping) to determine if the
> cell has a hyperlink

My hyperlinks are not in the "formula" fashion stated in the answer, but I love the general idea. Is there a way I can use a `class module` with `app level events` to watch for when cells are clicked and contain a hyperlink and see if user has `CTRL` pressed or not and follow hyperlink accordingly?

Bonus: How could I adjust the text that appears when you hover over a hyperlink to state accurately that CTRL + Click opens hyperlink.

> Answer from SU:

How I do this: Set the hyperlink with the URL in the second portion:

```
=HYPERLINK("","http://example.com")
```

In the VBA Editor make a module:

```
Declare Function GetKeyState Lib "User32" (ByVal vKey As Integer) As Integer
Global Const CTRL_KEY = 17
```

Then the worksheet code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo Error1
    If Left(Target.Formula, 10) = "=HYPERLINK" Then
        If GetKeyState(CTRL_KEY) < 0 Then 'Check if CTRL is held in
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Mid(Target.Formula, 16, Len(Target.Formula) - 17)
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If

    Exit Sub

Error1:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Update: I have an attack plan, but it will take some time for me to get it sorted. It's impossible to "trap" a hyperlink click before the link is opened. So, the only way for this to work is for me to convert all hyperlinks in a page to have the hyperlink in the "second part" then set the actual hyperlink to a reference to the cell itself and then I can get the above code modified.